# How to return the list object as a json format from spring controller of ajax get() method call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, spring

Please forgive me if my question is already matched with already any existing question.But I walked through so many threads of stackoverflow related solutions but I am unable to find any related solution of my question. Please help me. I am thankful to them.Thanks in advance.

Actual I am try to send list object  as a response of ajax call in the form of json format.

This is my code what I wrote for achieving this functionality,

`My Controller`

```java
 package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.daos.StudentDao;
import com.user.model.Student;

@Controller
public class Registration {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody List studentReg() {

        Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap();
        map1.put(1, "a");
        map1.put(2, "b");
        Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap();
        map2.put(3, "c");
        map2.put(4, "d");
        Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap();
        map3.put(5, "e");
        map3.put(6, "f");
        List<Map> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(map1);
        list.add(map2);
        list.add(map3);

        return list;
    }
}
```

`My spring cinfiguration file`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`And my Ajax call is`

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#abc").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
            type : "Get",
            url : "registration",
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Finally I am getting this exception while rendering response http://d.pr/i/lnzL
Please help me where I done wrong.Thanks in advance.And I add jackson jars to my classpath as well as lib folder.

Comment: maybe you have to add jackson jars in your classpath

Comment: @mserioli : I add those jars, Please see here http://d.pr/i/IM7T

Answer (score 1):

Browsers normally send Accept headers that clearly indicate they prefer HTML or XML responses. Spring has an XML converter registered by default, so it will jump in and claim that it can handle the response. But a vanilla `List` is not convertible to XML by default (though it is convertible to JSON). You can fix it by registering the `HttpMessageConverters` directly and ensuring that if there is an XML one it is preceded by the JSON one. (Spring Boot does this out of the box incidentally.) In Java you do it like this (to just convert JSON and nothing else):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.addAll(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}

}
```

In XML there is a namespace element for message converters I think (you should be able to find it with your XML editor).

You also need Jackson on your classpath (per comments). You can test if it's there by not using a browser to load the resource (e.g. use curl on the command line or one of the many restie tools, like a browser plugin that allows you to control the headers). E.g.

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" myhost/registration
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to reach you.Please can you elaborate this with any code snippets.

Comment: Added Java config example.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will apply this snippet with my code and I will get back you with final result.